# Getting $_POST not working after Ajax successful submit in same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I create a Form after user click on a div, and I submit on same page using Ajax without reloading page.

I see that the form is submitted successfully with data when I check the network tab in dev tools but **when I print $_POST or check if isset($_POST["data"]), I get $_POST is empty and the if condition is false**, is there any way to get the data in PHP ($_POST) without refreshing the page.

I get no errors in console or php

When using:

```
form.submit();
```

The form is submitted  and I get $_POST but the page reload, this is why I need to use Ajax

My code on Js page :

```
function post(path, parameters) {
    var form = $('<form id="form"></form>');

    form.attr("method", "post");
    form.attr("action", path);

    $.each(parameters, function(key, value) {
        var field = $('<input></input>');
        field.attr("type", "hidden");
        field.attr("name", key);
        field.attr("value", JSON.stringify(value));
        form.append(field);
        form.append(data);
    });

    $(document.body).append(form);  

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: path,
        data: $("#form").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          $('.before').hide();
          $('.next').show();
        }
    });
    return false;
}

$('.card-container').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = window.location.href;
    var object = {
    'array': [
      ['string1', 'string2'],
      ['string3', 'string4']
    ]
    };
    post(page, object);
});
```

My code on PHP page :

```
var_dump($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['array'])) {
    $array = json_decode($_POST['array'], true);
    print_r("ok");
}
```

The full code is too long to include it here.

Comment: Can you post the data from your network tab?

Comment: Similar to this :

Comment: array: [{"key":"value","key":"value"}]

Comment: `var page = "";` this is passing an empty path to `function post()`

Comment: You dont need to create a `<form>` element in your javascript. You can simply send an object with the `data` key of `$.ajax({})`

Comment: I used with var page = window.location.href; it's same result, since the form is submitted to the same page.

Comment: Do you use a framework? You have CSRF protection? Also add the error function to your AJAX, maybe you will see more: `error : function(xhr) {console.log(xhr);}`

Comment: Flame, can you explain more ? I tried to send the data like this too : $field="";
 
  $.each(parameters, function(key, value) {
        $field = key+":"+JSON.stringify(value)+","+$field;
  
    });
 $form =  "{"+$field.slice(0,-1)+"}";

Comment: I don't use a framework, only js, ajax, php, I am working on local now, I get no errors, the Ajax is submitting the data successfully

Comment: Can $_POST in PHP get the new values without refresh ?

Comment: You just don't need the form ....as mentioned above just send the object as data

Comment: "send the object as data" can you explain more ? an example ? will it solve the problem ?